# An app can’t load remote web content in the local context

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, requirejs

working on cordova [ windows 8.1 app ] maps api is not loading with error 
[Error] An app can’t load remote web content in the local context.

causes of issue :

1) google maps loads asyncly

2)  <strike>windows app doesn't allow dynamic script insertion</strike> 

3) win app runs in local context and doesn't allow to load anything from web(remote context) see this comment [ http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/09/25/apache-cordova-gains-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1-support-2-2/#comment-12911 ]

4) <strike>getting same error even in an iframe .</strike>

```
define('gmaps',['async!http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&sensor=false&libraries=geometry'],
        function(){
    // return the gmaps namespace for brevity
    return window.google.maps;
});
```

progress solved :

 2)  https://github.com/msopentech/winstore-jscompat

 4) able to load google map in i frame . now how can i pass google object to parent window ?

Update :


 **didn't find any solution for this issue 

 we switched to native app.**

Comment: Hi Sourabh, We are facing same issue while integrating google map for windows phone 8.1, Do you go the solutions for this or any work around for this solutions

Comment: Is there already a solution fot this? I'm working in a cordova-ionic project, and after trying a lot of solutions posted in the web, I can't make it work, It seems that windows (Phone) 8.1 can't load the google maps api (not even by using an iframe) #sad

Answer (score -1):

When you call a google maps api asynchronously You need put a callback in the end of the url, check this little example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async?hl=es

Now, you can play with google maps api with a callback trick defining before call asynchronously:

```
window["mycallback"] = function(){
    return "hello I'm called when all API is loaded :D"
}
```

And then calling with that url

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.17&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&callback=mycallback

Try with that, I hope to help with that

Comment: i am using require js plugin async which itself adds a callback and returns a gmap object.